# NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate when importing MonkeyRunner in Jython

Tags: android, jython, predicate, monkeyrunner

I want to use MonkeyRunner to generate MotionEvent (from screen touch). I have read the info  on
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html.

The problem is that for this jython program:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner

if __name__ == '__main__':
   # Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
   device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
```

I get the following error when executed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\jjungb00\python\workspace\monkey\src\runner.py",     line 6, in <module>
    from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicate

at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunner.classDictInit(MonkeyRunner.java:48)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

at org.python.core.PyJavaType.init(PyJavaType.java:534)

at org.python.core.PyType.createType(PyType.java:1264)

at org.python.core.PyType.addFromClass(PyType.java:1201)

at org.python.core.PyType.fromClass(PyType.java:1291)
```

...
skipping some stack trace
...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Predicate

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

...

I have added monkeyrunner.jar from the android sdk tool/lib as an external library.
I'm running on XP, with jython 2.5.2.

Any idea what to do? I guess I must add another library, but I do not know where or which.

Answer (score 9):

You need to add the Google Collections library - currently renamed to Guava. Look for guavalib.jar in the android SDK directory.

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. Adding the library helped, now I get a nullpointer exception instead, but it seem to be answered in other stackoverflow threads, like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038776/android-monkeyrunner-on-jython-has-got-null-pointerexception